# Creating a regex pattern with a variable for replacing a dot

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I need to replace the decimal separator in a string, and the decimal separators could be a dot `.` (e.g. English) or a comma `,` (e.g. German). So I have the variable `sep` for containing the separator string.

To convert the English-based decimal separator, I do the following replacement, but I got `,dd,dd` rather than `120,dd`:

```js
var sep = '.';
var numberStr = '120.31';
numberStr = numberStr.replace(new RegExp(sep + '\\d{2}', 'g'), ',dd');
console.log(numberStr);
```

Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot-character in RegularExpressions matches one single character, regardless of the actual character itself (details depending on the programming language / regex engine / flags in use).

If you want to *match* a dot, your separator should escape the regex dot-selector character like `var sep = '\\.';` to match an actual dot, not 'any single character'.

So your error occurs because in `120.31` the pattern `[any character followed by 2 numbers]` is found/replaced twice, once for `120` and once for `.31`, as `1` aswell as `.` match the regex dot-selector `'.'`.

For details see the [Regex Cheat Sheet](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#morechars)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the separator (so that it'll be treated by RegExp engine as is) by prefixing it with `\` character:

```
var escapedSep = sep.replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&");
numberStr = numberStr.replace(new RegExp(escapedSep + '\\d{2}', 'g'), ',dd');
```

Otherwise `.` is treated as a RegExp metacharacter, matching on any symbol (except line breaks).

Comment: To clarify on this ... (he answered before I could do), the regex ended on `.\d{2}` which means that the dot matches everything. To escape the dot, you have to add `\\ ` so that a dot is presented, not "matches everything except line breaks". But I should look to basst314's answer. Reason: those additional regex. That's uncalled for.

Comment: If you check my original answer, you see that was the first version. But did you think what happens when OP changes a separator?